# ASP.NET Core 5 MVC : different layouts for different areas

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have `Admin` under `Areas` and the folder structure is like this:

[image: Folder structure]

When entering `https://localhost:44393/admin`, the `ViewStart` cannot find `_AdminLayout.cshtml` and I get this error:

> InvalidOperationException: The layout view '_AdminLayout' could not be located.
> The following locations were searched:
> /Areas/Admin/Views/Home/_AdminLayout.cshtml,
> /Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml,
> /Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml

Inside Admin's `ViewStart.cshtml`, I have this

```
@{
    Layout = "_AdminLayout";
}
```

How do I fix this problem, when I am going `/admin` route to use admin layout.

Thank you!

Comment: Move your `/admin/shared` to be `/admin/views/shared`?

Comment: You need to give the relative path like `Layout = "~/Admin/Shared/_AdminLayout;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thank you guys, and //facepalm from my side.

I moved files to Views and now it is working.

Once the files are in the right place, it is enough to write in ViewStart.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout =  "_AdminLayout ";
}
```